# Импорт данных в готовую формулу

Tags: jquery, импорт

Есть готовая формула, в которую нужно подставлять значения из списка вместо "LOGO". Может есть другая программа, в которой это делается?

> Готовая формула:

```
else if($('#Bort').prop('checked')) {$('#image').attr('src','img/LOGO.jpg');}
```

Должно получиться:

```
else if($('#Bort').prop('checked')){$('#image').attr('src','img/kr_b2_nb_g_j_z_s_l.jpg');}
else if($('#Bort').prop('checked')) {$('#image').attr('src','img/kr_b2_nb_g_j_z_s_p.jpg');}
```

Значения для подстановки:

```
`kr_b2_nb_g_j_z_s_l 
kr_b2_nb_g_j_z_s_p 
kr_b_nb_g_j_z_s_l`
```

Comment: Заменить литерал на переменную. Которой и присваивать нужное в текущий кол времени значение.

Comment: @Akina мне комбинаторику нужно использовать?

Comment: Не понял фразы... Наверное, Вы как-то иначе понимаете слово "комбинаторика".

Comment: @Akina можете мне какие-нибудь примеры скинуть, что бы примерно понять?

Comment: ``else if($('#Bort').prop('checked')) {$('#image').attr('src','img/' & varValueToInsert & '.jpg');}``

Comment: @Akina а как переменные объявить? varValueToInsert = ["kr_b2_nb_g_j_z_s_l", "kr_b2_nb_g_j_z_s_p", "kr_b_nb_g_j_z_s_l"];

Comment: @Akina и как ему нати нужную картинку?для $('#Bort').prop('checked') нужно, что бы подставлялось kr_b_nb_g_j_z_s_l

Comment: @Akina поняла,что не правильно задала условие вначале..